# Handling States.Runtime errors in AWS Step Functions

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

I am using AWS Step functions for an automation solution and the execution is stopping because of a Runtime exception.I added a catch block to catch the States.Runtime exception and when it occurs it should go to the next task defined,but it does not reach there an stops at the block where the exception happened. Here is my Step function definition:

```
    {
  "Comment": "Terminate a Tagged EC2 Instance",
  "StartAt": "DescribeInstances",
  "States": {
    "DescribeInstances": {
      "ResultPath": "$.DescribeInstances",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::aws-sdk:ec2:describeInstances",
      "Type": "Task",
      "Parameters": {
        "InstanceIds.$": "$.Params.InstanceIds"
      },
      "ResultSelector": {
        "Value.$": "$.Reservations[0].Instances[0].Tags[0].Value"
      },
      
      "Catch": [
        {
          "ErrorEquals": [
            "States.Runtime"
          ],
          "Next": "RuntimeErrorFallback"
        }
      ],
      "Next": "isInstanceTagged"
    },
    "isInstanceTagged": {
      "Type": "Choice",
      "Choices": [
        {
          "Variable": "$.DescribeInstances.Value",
          "StringEquals": "true",
          "Next": "TerminateInstances"
        },
        {
          "Not": {
            "Variable": "$.DescribeInstances.Value",
            "StringEquals": "true"
          },
          "Next": "send_email2"
        }
      ]
    },
    "TerminateInstances": {
      "ResultPath": "$.TerminateInstances",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::aws-sdk:ec2:terminateInstances",
      "Type": "Task",
      "Parameters": {
        "InstanceIds.$": "$.Params.InstanceIds"
      },
     
      "Next": "send_email"
    },
    "send_email": {
      "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:1111111:function:send_email",
      "Type": "Task",
      "End": true
    },
    "send_email2": {
      "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:1111111:function:send_email",
      "Type": "Task",
      "End": true
    },
    "RuntimeErrorFallback": {
      "Type": "Pass",
      "Result": "This is a fallback for Runtime Error",
      "End": true
    }
  }
}
```

Is there anything I am missing so that I can handle this correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you cannot catch `States.Runtime` errors.

"An execution failed due to some exception that it couldn't process. Often these are caused by errors at runtime, such as attempting to apply InputPath or OutputPath on a null JSON payload. A States.Runtime error isn't retriable, and will always cause the execution to fail. A retry or catch on States.ALL won't catch States.Runtime errors." -- From [Step Functions documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/concepts-error-handling.html#states-runtime-error).

The most common case for this type of scenario is when the JSON Path you specified in your definition conflicts with the input to your state or the results from a [Task](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-task-state.html).

In your particular case, you are getting the error because your [ResultSelector](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/input-output-inputpath-params.html#input-output-resultselector) value references the first item in an array of named tags which the EC2 [DescribeInstances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeInstances.html) will only return if the instance is tagged. If the instance has no tags, the path you specified is not present and you will get a `States.Runtime` error. To handle this, I suggest you not use ResultSelector and instead return the full response to your [Choice state](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-choice-state.html). You can then use the `IsPresent` comparison operator to check for the existence in the first statement in the first [ChoiceRule](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-choice-state.html#amazon-states-language-choice-state-rules) and take the necessary action (in your case, that seems to be to go to the `send_email2` state). These rules and statements are evaluated in order so you can safely reference that path in subsequent statements without risk of the error. I've provided an [ASL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/concepts-amazon-states-language.html) example below that includes this approach.

Your state machine is also prone to `States.Runtime` errors if the  input either doesn't have the required array of InstanceIds or the input contains a string rather than an array of strings (as required by the API). If that's the case, the example demonstrates how to handle this. The first [choice](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-choice-state.html) condition confirms that the referenced item exists, then sends to a [Fail state](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-fail-state.html) if not (you could take some other compensating action). If it's present but is a string instead of an array, then it will transform to an array using the [States.Array intrinsic function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-intrinsic-functions.html#asl-intrsc-func-arrays).

```
{
  "StartAt": "Check for Instance Ids",
  "States": {
    "Check for Instance Ids": {
      "Type": "Choice",
      "Choices": [
        {
          "Not": {
            "Variable": "$.Params.InstanceIds",
            "IsPresent": true
          },
          "Next": "No Instance Ids"
        },
        {
          "Variable": "$.Params.InstanceIds",
          "IsString": true,
          "Next": "Transform To Array"
        }
      ],
      "Default": "DescribeInstances"
    },
    "No Instance Ids": {
      "Type": "Fail",
      "Error": "InvalidInput",
      "Cause": "The required value $.Params.InstanceIds was not provided"
    },
    "Transform To Array": {
      "Type": "Pass",
      "Next": "DescribeInstances",
      "Parameters": {
        "Params": {
          "InstanceIds.$": "States.Array($.Params.InstanceIds)"
        }
      }
    },
    "DescribeInstances": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Next": "isInstanceTagged",
      "Parameters": {
        "InstanceIds.$": "$.Params.InstanceIds"
      },
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::aws-sdk:ec2:describeInstances",
      "ResultPath": "$.DescribeInstances"
    },
    "isInstanceTagged": {
      "Type": "Choice",
      "Choices": [
        {
          "Or": [
            {
              "Not": {
                "Variable": "$.DescribeInstances.Reservations[0].Instances[0].Tags[0].Value",
                "IsPresent": true
              }
            },
            {
              "Not": {
                "Variable": "$.DescribeInstances.Reservations[0].Instances[0].Tags[0].Value",
                "StringEquals": "true"
              }
            }
          ],
          "Next": "send_email2"
        },
        {
          "Variable": "$.DescribeInstances.Reservations[0].Instances[0].Tags[0].Value",
          "StringEquals": "true",
          "Next": "TerminateInstances"
        }
      ]
    },
    "send_email2": {
      "Type": "Pass",
      "End": true
    },
    "TerminateInstances": {
      "Type": "Pass",
      "Next": "send_email"
    },
    "send_email": {
      "Type": "Pass",
      "End": true
    }
  }
}
```

Note that your logic also appears brittle as it looks only at the first tag and only at the value of the tag. I suspect you provided this as a simplified example and that your real workflow will have more comprehensive logic.

Comment: In my condition, I am tagging an EC2 instance with a tag which contains a Key/Value pair. Now when I run the DescribeInstances state, if the EC2 instance is not tagged, it fails and throws States.Runtime error. Given your above solution can we check for the presence of Tags or not?